# Creating an additional column in sink using logic that involves three different columns from three different source tables respectively

Tags: azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow, data-transform

What will be the steps and expression for derived column if the logic for populating the column is as below:

The data mapping is  using data factory:

```
select c.ClaimID, pl. Related StoreNumber as StoreNumber from claim c
inner join ClaimToProviderToProviderToLocation ctptptl on ctptptl. ClaimID = c. ClaimID
inner join ProviderToProviderToLocation ptptl on ptptl. ProviderToProviderToLocationID = ctptptl. ProviderToProviderToLocationID
inner join ProviderLocation pl on pl. ProviderLocationID = ptptl. ProviderLocationID
Order by c. ClaimID desc
```

The data mapping is happening in between Source sql server to Azure Database using azure data factory.

I tried adding a data flow activity where i added three inner joins to get columns involved in the join. Then i added a derived column transformation, to finally add expression for StoreNumber,but i am unable to see columns from the first two tables/streams if i add derived column right after 3rd join.

Comment: What error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

After the join transformation, if you want to use any column in the next transformation, join will give the columns like below.

[image]

You need to give the column name in the derived column, and you can use any column as per your requirement from the column list from the previous join transformation.

[image]

Here, for sample I have used two joins and you can see I am able to use column from first source.